# Check server status and output in HTML

Tags: php, html, server, status

I'm trying to output the status of a server (online/offline) in html.

I have a PHP snippet that checks the status of the server but I need the output to be in HTML format so I can use it elsewhere on my website.

I'm running wordpress with the tablera plugin, I want to output the status (just online or offline text) in the table but it does not accept PHP, only HTML.

Edit:
This is my PHP snippet:

```
<?php
$array="www.php.net:80";
$fp = @fsockopen($array[0], $array[1], $errno, $errstr,1);
if(!$fp){             
$status = $array[0]."==><font color=\"#FF0000\">online</font>";
}
else{              
$status = $array[0]."==><font color=\"#FF0000\">offline</font>";
}
fclose($fp);
echo $status;
?>
```

It just needs to check if the server is online or offline, if it's online it should display 'online' if its offline, it should display 'offline'.

Comment: If the server is offline, how will anything work?

Comment: @j08691 — Presumably it checks a *different* server

Comment: Very obviously it's 2 servers we're talking about here ... One that does the checking and one that is the subject of the status checking.

Comment: since you didn't share your PHP snippet, let's suppose you have a `is_server_online()` function that returns `true` or `false`, all you need is `if (is_server_online()) { echo "Online";} else { echo "Offline"; }`.

Comment: Really hard to tell what you are asking; how can any WordPress page not accept php?

Comment: And your array is not an array but a string.

Answer (score 0):

This script checks your server to see if the server is online or not.

```
<?php
if (fsockopen('www.yourwebsite.com', 80)) {
    echo('Reports Online');
} else {
    echo('Reports Offline');
}
?>
```